# Change default firebase database programmatically and run the same firebase functions both on default and secondary database

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

Background - 
I'm setting up a new feature that allows users to select which city they are in, since my app is a public transportation app. I would like cities to be in separate databases, and for that I have created a secondary database in my firebase project. It's a React Native App and I'm using react-native-firebase.

Question 1 -
When the users selects a different city, I would like that database to be his default database. I couldn't figure out how to do this, can anyone help?

I've tried initializing and just changing the databaseURL, and even though I connected to the second DB once, it didn't do so every time. Seemed like an unstable solution.

The other solution I found would be to pass the url to every "firebase.database(url)", but that seems like a bad solution.

Question 2 - 
Since the app is exactly the same on both cities, I would like to run the same functions I already run on DB1, on DB2. They are completely separate DBs, but with the exact same nodes. Both have a "location" node, for example, and then I have a listener for changes there. How do I set up listeners on both databases with just one function? Or do I need to get a reference to DB2 and just duplicate the functions?

Comment: I answered your first question below. The second question seems unrelated, so please open a separate question for that. I understand that they may all be one big problem to you, but on Stack Overflow the fact that I can answer one without addressing the other means that you should post them separately.

Comment: Thanks, I posted it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/56671834/8754782

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of a default database per user. That means that you'll want to initialize Firebase from your JavaScript code as shown in the [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/core/initialize-apps#Cross-Platform-Example) documentation:

> ```
> // pluck values from your `GoogleService-Info.plist` you created on the firebase console
> const iosConfig = {
>   clientId: 'x',
>   appId: 'x',
>   apiKey: 'x',
>   databaseURL: 'x',
>   storageBucket: 'x',
>   messagingSenderId: 'x',
>   projectId: 'x',
>
>   // enable persistence by adding the below flag
>   persistence: true,
> };
>
> // pluck values from your `google-services.json` file you created on the firebase console
> const androidConfig = {
>   clientId: 'x',
>   appId: 'x',
>   apiKey: 'x',
>   databaseURL: 'x',
>   storageBucket: 'x',
>   messagingSenderId: 'x',
>   projectId: 'x',
>
>   // enable persistence by adding the below flag
>   persistence: true,
> };
>
> const kittensApp = firebase.initializeApp(
>   // use platform specific firebase config
>   Platform.OS === 'ios' ? iosConfig : androidConfig,
>   // name of this app
>   'kittens',
> );
>
> // dynamically created apps aren't available immediately due to the
> // asynchronous nature of react native bridging, therefore you must
> // wait for an `onReady` state before calling any modules/methods
> // otherwise you will most likely run into `app not initialized` exceptions
> kittensApp.onReady().then((app) => {
>    // --- ready ---
>    // use `app` arg, kittensApp var or `app('kittens')` to access modules
>    // and their methods. e.g:
>    firebase.app('kittens').auth().signInAnonymously().then((user) => {
>        console.log('kittensApp user ->', user.toJSON());
>    });
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

Assuming that I pass the databaseURL to the config based on user selection of the city, wouldn't it be his default database? That is kind of what I tried to do, but didn't work very well. I'll try again.

Any tips on Question 2?

Comment: If you configure a `FirebaseApp` with a specific database URL, that app will interact with *that* database.

Comment: If you tried something that didn't work, edit your question to include the [minimum code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It was working, just silly me forgot to change the reference I was logging. Thank you for the help!